# Using dynamic in .NET Standard library

Tags: c#, .net, dynamic, .net-standard

this problem's been driving me mad for a while now, I'm making use of the dynamic type in part of my library (targeting .NET Standard 1.2 & 2.0 + .NET Framework 3.5). I've added a reference to `Microsoft.CSharp` which has added correctly to the .NET Standard versions of my project (`Microsoft.CSharp` & `System.Runtime.Binding` in v1.2, `Microsoft.CSharp` in v2.0).

From browsing the web, it seems like this should be enough to get things working, but I keep getting the error:

> Missing compiler required member 'Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.CSharpArgumentInfo.Create'

in the .NET Standard 2.0 build.

I've tried numerous project cleans & rebuilds, using various different versions of Microsoft.CSharp, manually added System.Runtime.Binding into v2.0, whatever I try it still keeps coming up with the same error. Does anyone have any further suggestions of things to try?

Kind regards
James

Answer (score 3):

The `dynamic` keyword was introduced in C# 4.0 which requires .NET Framework 4.0, you're targeting .NET 3.5 therefore the dynamic keyword is not available.

Comment: Ah, whoops, should have thought to check that. Doesn't help with Visual Studio throwing me a red herring saying the problem's with my standard build though. I'll try updating the framework version to 4.0 and see if it helps. Thank you

Comment: You can actually target version 4.5.1 as .NET Standard 1.2 is compatible with .NET 4.5.1, this will let you make use of C# 5

Comment: I actually deliberately set it to a really old version of .NET framework because I know some users are stuck on framework 4.0, targeting 3.5 was just to cast the net extra wide in what I support. For my own understanding, if I'm already targeting .NET Standard 1.2, is there any benefit to also targeting 4.5.1? Wouldn't I already be targeting it implicitly by the fact I'm targeting the corresponding .NET standard version?